# How can I get my app to get the URL of a link clicked in WebView, perform operations on it, and then load it?

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm going to preface this by saying I am an absolute noob at coding anything in Android (I'm basically learning how to do everything through you awesome guys and gals at Stack Overflow :) ). I am making an app that is completely just a WebView component and I want it to detect when a link in that WebView page has been clicked, get the url of that link, and then redirect the user to a different link if the original link has a certain string in it. Finally, the WebView needs to be reloaded either with the original link or redirected link.

Here's my code for the java side of the app where I think the error is happening:

```
public class Grades extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webview;
    String ShowOrHideWebViewInitialUse = "show";
    private ProgressBar spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grades);

        webview =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        spinner = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());

        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
        webview.loadUrl("myurl.com");
    }
    // This allows for a splash screen
    // (and hide elements once the page loads)
    private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView webview, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // only make it invisible the FIRST time the app is run
            if (ShowOrHideWebViewInitialUse.equals("show")) {
                webview.setVisibility(webview.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ShowOrHideWebViewInitialUse = "hide";
            view.setVisibility(webview.VISIBLE);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.contains("/courses/")) {
                url = url + "/grades"
                WebView.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            } else {
                WebView.loadUrl(url)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I did some troubleshooting and added code that made the app display the url in the logcat in the last @override. The problem there was that the WebView didn't load the page, instead there was just an endless loop in the logcat of it printing the url of the *current* page for the WebView, not the url of the *link*. So to me it seems that my problem is twofold and I have no idea what to do.

For info: the middle two @overrides are just for displaying a spinner while the main page is loading when the app starts up. Everything seems to work fine until the last @override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The last override should be:

```
@Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        System.out.println(Uri.parse(url).getHost());
        if ("myurl.com".equals(Uri.parse(url).getHost())) {
            webview.loadUrl(url);
            String newurl = webview.getUrl();
            System.out.println(newurl);
            if (newurl.contains("/grades") || newurl.contains("/users") || newurl.contains("/assignments")) {
                webview.loadUrl(newurl);
                return false;
            }
            if (newurl.contains("myurl.com") && newurl.contains("/grades") == false && newurl.contains("/users") == false && newurl.contains("/assignments") == false) {
                newurl = newurl + "/grades";
                System.out.println(newurl);
                webview.loadUrl(newurl);
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add return statement to end of overriden function and change return value due url change.